# How to enable user themes in Gsettings (Gnome-Tweaks)

Tags: 18.04, gnome, themes, gsettings

I am working in a chroot environment, and I need a command in terminal to set gnome-shell themes. In this case I'm wondering how I switch the "user-themes" setting on the gnome-tweaks extension tab (see photo). Switching via the GUI is easy, but so far I don't know how to do it from the command line.

[image: I need to enable this extension in terminal]

Comment: hi, what do you mean by little black screen? the terminal? if you want to change the look of your terminal, that is done from the settings menu in the terminal itself.

Comment: I need to a command in terminal to set gnome-shell themes.

Answer (score 1):

First, to install the "user themes" extension using the terminal, if you haven't already, you can run the following command:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions
```

This will install the "user themes" extension along with a bunch of other extensions.

You don't have to use `gsettings`, unless you need to. You can enable the extensions you want using `gnome-shell-extension-tool`. Specifically, to enable "user themes", the command you need to run is

```
gnome-shell-extension-tool -e user-themes
```

Parameter `-e` tells `gnome-shell-extension-tool` to enable the extension.

You can also disable an extension using the `-d` parameter instead of `-e`.

Answer (score 1):

first get the enabled-extensions with below command

`gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions`

example;

```
pratap@i7:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions
['dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com']
pratap@i7:~$
```

then add your extension name to the output you got

example;

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions "['dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com', 'user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com']"
```

Answer (score 0):

In new versions, the commands above are deprecated. The new command is:

```
gnome-extensions COMMAND
```

If you want more info about the commands type:

```
gnome-extensions help
```

And for enabling or disabling the extension "user themes":

```
gnome-extensions enable/disable user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```